# why is Laravel executing the last matching route?

Tags: laravel, routes

I just started a new project in Laravel. I read Laravel supposed to go to the first matching route but in here it is going to the last matching route. if I delete the third route it goes to second route. why is this behavior?

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello, World!';
});
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello, World 2!';
});
```

Comment: Why are you using the same / for those different responses?  At what point would it go for the first or second?   Laravel reads all those / routes and uses the last one.

Comment: I am just learning. I am testing Laravel logic and I am surprised to see it is acting differently to its written logic

Comment: *"I read Laravel supposed to go to the first matching route"* - Out of curiosity, where did you read that? But yes, your issue is when using the same Route `/` for all of these, it takes the last one. This can be a much bigger issue if you use Route Params, like `Route::get('/{example}', ...)` and `Route::get('/one', ...)`; depending on the order of those Routes, if you navigated to `http://localhost:8000/one`, you might get the wrong logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way you want to see it is like a book. It reads page 1, 2 and 3. And it ends at 3, meaning it will show you that page. So it will always show "Hello, world 2"

So what you wanna do is implement it along these lines:

```
Route::get('/one', function () {
    return 'Hello, World!';
});
Route::get('/two', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/three', function () {
    return 'Hello, World 2!';
});
```

Here is a good reference for how its setup by default for a controller

```
/**
 * Actions Handled By Resource Controller
 * Verb         URI                     Action          Route Name              View
 * GET          /photos                 index           photos.index            index.blade.php
 * POST         /photos                 store           photos.store            (r)edirect to action: 'edit' or 'index' or 'create'
 * GET          /photos/{photo}         show            photos.show             show.blade.php
 * PUT/PATCH    /photos/{photo}         update          photos.update           (r)edirect to action: 'edit' or 'index'
 * DELETE       /photos/{photo}         destroy         photos.destroy          (r)edirect to action: 'index'
*/
```

So at the end of it, your route could look like the following

```
Route::get('/', [WelcomeController::class, 'welcome']);
```

Or if you want to use all the functions in a controller:

```
Route::resource('/', WelcomeController::class);
// Uses all the default resources available (see actions in reference list).
// Your can also add "->only(['index', 'show']);" to the end or "->exept([]);" the same way
```